# Can you explain the magic up?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Why you native english speaker guys always use up with verbs? To emphesize? Like point and point out ? Or like is there big difference between:

- let's pull a chair
- let's pull up a char

Or,

- read this book
- read up this book

What is the exact point here? When should I use those?

Comment: You need to do some research on [**phrasal verbs**](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+are+phrasal+verbs+and+when+to+use+them)

Comment: I know phrasal verbs . but in those cases these verbs has similar meanings at least i assume that way

Comment: Well, you assume wrong, I'm afraid. (Also, "read up this book" is wrong. You can _read up on_ a subject, but you can't read up a book.)

Comment: As J.R. (+1) points out, you non-native English speaker guys need to like study phrasal verbs more thoroughly. (We native English speakers guys always like capitalize the names of languages, too.)

Comment: There is no such verb as "explain up".  The meaning of the **ex** prefix in **explain** (a verb of Latin origin) runs counter to the meaning of the English **up**, and so they won't be found paired.  "Explain" means to lay something *out*, whereas **up** conveys the idea of completion or of reaching the destination.  Native speakers intuit the meaning of **ex** without having to study etymology or Latin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English has numerous *phrasal verbs*, or verbs that appear with a preposition, and usually also have a different meaning than the verb without the preposition.

However, sometimes there is no big change in meaning.

In these cases, *up* a lot of times means "completely" or "thoroughly":

> Clean this mess up = Clean the mess completely.
>
> Read up on your history, you don't know what you are talking about = Read thoroughly on your history (implication: you need to be educated)

*Up*, while it typically means "above", can also mean "toward with the intent of ending the motion near X" with verbs of motion.

> Pull up a chair = Pull a chair toward me.
>
> The cat snuck up on the mouse = The cat snuck toward the mouse.
>
> Walk up to the counter = Walk toward the counter.

And of course there's verbs where *up* changes the meaning into something related, but different.

> I added another task to my list. (My task list gained a task.)
>
> The numbers don't add up. (The numbers don't total what I expect.)
>
> I dug a hole for the firepit. (There's a spot somewhere missing some dirt.)
>
> I dug up information on the suspect. (I went through a lot of information to find things I wanted.)

Comment: I'd argue that the "dug up" example belongs in the second category since it's a figurative use of a literal phrase where the end result is bringing the thing you unearthed towards you.  Otherwise, great answer.